# Alphanumeric sorting for Sql Server CE

Tags: sql-server, windows-ce, sql-server-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting Alphanumeric field in SQL CE (Compact Edition) version 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285504/sorting-alphanumeric-field-in-sql-ce-compact-edition-version-3-5)

How to make alphanumeric sorting for Sql Server CE ?

Stored values example:

```
1,2,20,3,a1,a2,a20,a3
```

Output values:

```
1,2,3,20,a1,a2,a3,a20
```

CE does not support `IsNumeric` function, so it cannot be used.
 CE version has to be 3.5, because Visual Basic 2010 does not support CE 4.0.

Solution like this does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

This might be because of those brackets, CE seems ignoring them.

In Sql Server 2008 I have used following for alphanumeric sorting:

```
 SELECT Id FROM Test
 ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN IsNumeric(ID) = 1 THEN Right(Replicate('0',21) + ID, 20)
 WHEN IsNumeric(ID) = 0 THEN Left ( ID + Replicate('',21),20)
 ELSE ID
 END
```

How could this same be done in CE ?

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work for the numeric values.  For the values with characters, you would probably need to split the characters out to sort the following numbers alphabetically.  The case Alex K. referenced will work for that.

```
DECLARE @padding varchar(10)
SELECT @padding = '000000000'

select *
from YourTable
order by SUBSTRING(@padding, 0, 10 - LEN(yourValue)) + yourValue
```